# How do I find the limit for part c?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Find each of the following limits, or explain that the limit does not exist.

Let $f(x,y) =\begin{cases} x^2&, x \geq 0\\ 
             x^3&, x < 0 \\
 \end{cases}$

a) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(3,-2)$;

b) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches, $(-2,1)$;

c) limit of $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.

I already tried doing the whole problem, but I'm not sure if I got it right. I had 9 for part a, -8 for part b, and I got 0 for part c but this is the one I'm hesitant about. Help is appreciated!

Comment: I may be missing something, but it looks like $f$ is essentially just a function of one variable? $y$ doesn't seem to have any affect on the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the limit both sides

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x,y)\ \  \text{and} \ \ \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x,y)$$